# Jackson polymorphic deserialization based on property substring

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind, objectmapper

Consider this JSON array:

```json
[
   {
      "type": "xyz-foo",
      "info": {
         "name": "John",
         "age": 20,
         "company": "some company"
      }
   },
   {
      "type": "xyz-bar",
      "info": {
         "name": "Tom",
         "age": 10,
         "school": "some school"
      }
   }
]
```

and I have a POJO like this

```java
class Pojo {
   private String type;
   
   @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type",
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = {@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FooInfo.class, name = "foo"),
    @JsonSubTypes(value = {@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BarInfo.class, name = "bar")})
   private Info info;
}
```

Obviously, this will not work because type is neither `foo` nor `bar`. And I get an error saying

> Could not resolve type id 'xyz-foo' as a subtype of `Info`: known type
> ids = [foo, bar] (for POJO property 'info')

Is there anyway to match the subclass based on the substring?

Comment: Jackson does not directly support matching on substrings for type identification. The @JsonSubTypes annotation in Jackson requires an exact match on the name field. Potential solution to your problem is to implement a custom deserializer. This allows you to define your own logic to match the type field in your JSON to the correct subclass.

Comment: It's a good question and tricky one. So, consider offering a bounty for this question given the effort it will take.

Comment: Why can't you use `name="xyz-bar"` in the `Type` annotation, or do you mean that `xyz` can be anything and varies?

Comment: @Kozydot I tried using a custom deserializer but the problem is wouldn't I have to manually deserialize ```Pojo Class``` to have access to ```type```, handling not just ```Info``` but other properties in ```Pojo Class```? In the example, there are only ```type``` and ```info``` properties but I have a bunch more in the actual ```Pojo Class```.

Comment: @AnishB. Not sure how to offer a bounty

Comment: @MarkRotteveelyes ```xyz``` varies. type can be identified by the last substring ```foo/bar```

Comment: @pizza Yes, you are correct. Using a custom deserializer for the entire class would mean you have to manually handle the deserialization of all properties in the class. This can be tedious and error-prone, especially if your class has a lot of properties. A better approach would be to use a custom deserializer just for the `info` field, and let Jackson handle the deserialization of the other fields automatically.

Comment: @Kozydot sure thanks for the suggestion. But how do I pass "type" to the deserializer?

Comment: @pizza You can use the ContextualDeserializer interface, which allows you to create a deserializer that is aware of the context in which it is being used.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you cane remove this annotion **`@JsonTypeInfo(...)`**

Your POJO

```
class Pojo {
   private String type;
   private Info info;

  // Getter & Setter
}
```

It will work. Let me know